apple mlx.core AttributeError: module 'mlx.core' has no attribute 'array'
enter image description here
Why is the core red?
confusing? I print it this way, and I can see there is an array
enter image description here
Does anyone understand? Thanks!

python version:

Python 3.10.14 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Mar 20 2024, 12:51:49) [Clang 16.0.6 ] on darwin

mlx version:

mlx                       0.15.1          py310h481d4a5_0    conda-forge

device info:

Model Name: MacBook Pro
Chip: Apple M3 Pro
Memory: 36 GB
System Version: macOS 15.0

Please read Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors? You can [edit] your question and replace the images with [code block]s. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.
